# Jboss 5.1 GA won't start -Eclipse Kepler

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

my Jboss 5.1 only stay in this line

> 13:09:09,477 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA
>   (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 40s:834ms

My overview :

```
JNDI: 1099
web: 8280 
Startup poller: web 
Listen on all interfaces OK
```

JRE `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle`

Answer (score -1):

Use the jdk 1.7.0_80 from oracle official site. 
Reinstall the jboss 5.1 
Use a custom deploy and tmp folder from the server folder 
Use the Copy projects into workspace option when you import the project 
Uncheck the Deployment Scanners option 
I have ten folders in my server: conf, data, default, 
deploy, deployers, "MyAppName", lib, log, tmp, log. 
Make sure about that!!!